# WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. With Requests and Beastuifulsoup

Tags: python, encoding, request, beautifulsoup

I had this web scraping code working a few minutes ago, but now I get this warning and encoding. Since this request doesn't return html, Beautifulsoup is returning a None type when I search for the contents of a  tag. What is going wrong here? I tried to google a bit for this encoding problem, but couldn't find a clear answer.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&fr=uh3_finance_web&uhb=uhb2'

data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content).text
print(data)
```

Here are the results:

```
0.0 seconds
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]>
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
<Response [200]> 
{}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: First can't reproduce. Second `soup` is  string in your case not `BeautifulSoup` object

Answer (score 21):

The constructor of Beautifulsoup below worked for me:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_path, 'r'),"html.parser",from_encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response = urlopen(notiurl)
html = response.read().decode(encoding="iso-8859-1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

check the coding--->`print(soup.original_encoding)`

DOCUMENTATION ----> https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings